# How can I call New-AzureStorageContext using -SasToken instead of -StorageAccountKey

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

Using Azure Powershell v1.3, I'm trying to create a new storage context using an existing Shared Access Signature token which references an existing policy. When I call `New-AzureStorageContext` with `-SasToken` and `-StorageAccountName` I get an error:

```
PS C:\> $ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -SasToken '?sr=c&sv=2015-02-21&si=ReadOnly&sig=<signature omitted>=&api-version=2015-04-05' -StorageAccountName 'mystorageaccount'

New-AzureStorageContext : An item with the same key has already been added.
At line:1 char:8
```

I feel like I'm getting the format of the SAS token wrong, or am missing a step or parameter, but there are no examples on what it should look like, and this is the only SAS form I've been able to query from Azure.

Note I don't want to use `New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken` (which all examples use) because I already have a token, and just want to use it for read-only purposes, so I don't need to use the storage account keys. Creating a new one would require permissions I don't want this client to have.

What is the missing syntax / step?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think this looks like a bug in PowerShell Cmdlets. If my SAS Token has `api-version` parameter, I get the same error as you're getting. If I remove it, the error's gone. I used the SAS Token with and without `api-version` and it worked just fine.

Comment: Actually it is a bug in storage client library!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've discovered a bug in Storage Client Library. I traced the code from PowerShell to Storage Client Library and here's what I found. PowerShell Cmdlet code tries to create a `StorageCredentials` object by passing this SAS Token.

```
    public StorageCredentials(string sasToken)
    {
        CommonUtility.AssertNotNullOrEmpty("sasToken", sasToken);

        this.SASToken = sasToken;
        this.UpdateQueryBuilder();
    }

    private void UpdateQueryBuilder()
    {
        SasQueryBuilder newQueryBuilder = new SasQueryBuilder(this.SASToken);

        newQueryBuilder.Add(Constants.QueryConstants.ApiVersion, Constants.HeaderConstants.TargetStorageVersion);

        this.queryBuilder = newQueryBuilder;
    }
```

Now if you look at the code for `UpdateQueryBuilder`, it tries to add `api-version` again without checking if this is already there.

I created an issue on Github for this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/259.

Comment: Thanks! Way to go on submitting the issue. That may be the fastest follow-up by MS I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old one but now Storage Context is working with SAS:

```
$resourceGroup="YourResourceGroupName"
$storAccName = "YourStorageAccountName"

# get Storage Key
$storKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $storAccName).Value[0]

# create main Storage Context
$storCont = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storAccName -StorageAccountKey $storKey

# create SAS token
$storSAS = New-AzureStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob, Queue -ResourceType Service, Container, Object -Permission "rwdalucp" -Context $storCont

# create SAS-based Storage Context
$storContSAS = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storAccName -SasToken $storSAS
```